# Does the SQL query generated from an IQueryable continue to execute after the C# program stops enumerating?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, database-cursor

I have a database with a huge number of records. I have record filtering criteria that cannot be translated into SQL. Consider the following scenario:

```cs
IItemRepository repo = new ItemRepository();
IQueryable<Item> items = repo.GetAll();
IEnumerator<Item> itemEnumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
List<BinaryData> binaryDataList = new List<BinaryData>();

while (binaryDataList.Count < 20 && itemEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    BinaryData binaryData = BinaryData.Extract(itemEnumerator.Current.BinaryData);

    if (IsValidBinaryData(binaryData))
    {
        binaryDataList.Add(binaryData);
    }
}
```

Once the program exits the `while` loop, does the query continue to execute on the server or does it stop? I need it to stop, because executing a `GetAll()` query on this database would be madness.

**edit:** I've oversimplified the scenario, in the actual case there are some filters and ordering, but this there's no point in copy and pasting that complex code.

Comment: You will be effectively running `GetAll` on the server.

Comment: @mjwills Is there no way to stop it?

Comment: Hmmm... So `Take(1)` on each iteration? Actually considered this but will this not take the same row each time?

Comment: I'd suggest using `Take(20)` and `Skip` as necessary.

Comment: As far as I know, ALL data will be returned when you do items.GetEnumerator().

Comment: @mjwills This won't work for my case. I won't end up with 20 items at the end if those top 20 items don't meet the criteria that I can only determine in C# code. What would work (although it doesn't sound good) is to `Take(i+1)` on each iteration and `Skip(i)`.

Comment: Skip _then_ Take.

Comment: So `Skip(i)`, `Take(1)`, yeah, good point.

Comment: Well, `Take(binaryDataList.Count - 20)` but yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paging is a great way of dealing with many results.

Your comment suggests that your know about `Take` and `Skip`.

[Implement Efficient Data Paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/implement-efficient-data-paging) has a full example. Here is a tiny part of it.

> ```
> public IQueryable<Dinner> FindUpcomingDinners() 
>
> (...)
>
> var upcomingDinners = dinnerRepository.FindUpcomingDinners();
>
> var paginatedDinners = upcomingDinners.Skip((page ?? 0) * pageSize)
>                                          .Take(pageSize)
>                                          .ToList();
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> Entity Framework is smart enough to construct an optimized SQL query that performs this skipping logic in the SQL database – and not in the web-server. This means that even if we have millions of upcoming Dinners in the database, only the 10 we want will be retrieved as part of this request (making it efficient and scalable).

---

## The question

> Once the program exits the while loop, does the query continue to execute on the server or does it stop? I need it to stop, because executing a GetAll() query on this database would be madness.

There is not 'continuing' to execute the query. The code does **not** fetch records one by one when `IQueryable` is enumerated. At the point of enumeration the query is send to the database, all results are fetched and then stored in memory.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer: answers my questions and provides the method to do it.